# Does there exist such function or not?

Tags: calculus

There exists a function $f$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = 25$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 5$

I am confused, I do not whether it is true or not

I have a counter-example, but I think thre might be such function

Comment: If both limits are true, the ratio of the two limits should be 5.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
Suppose that such a function exists. Note that
$$
25=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}\times \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

It can't exist since :

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} =\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0\cdot5=0$$

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a function.
To prove that, let $f$ be a solution.
The conditions on the limits impose that $f$ does not vanish near $+ \infty $.
Therefore, the ratio of the too quantities is $x$ and the limit of $x$ near $ + \infty $ is $ +\infty$ and not $ 5 / 25 $.
Another way of seeing that :
If $ f(x)/x $ has 5 as a limit, $f(x)/x^2$ has $0$ as a limit.

Answer (score 0):

In this case,

$lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2} = 25 = 5*5 =5* lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} $

so,

$lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x = 5$

this gives a contradiction in the statement.